# Including jquery.tools.js breaks other jquery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-tools

I am using some jquery for rating features and enlarge images on my website. This is all working well until I include: http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/jquery.tools.min.js. At this point the Mozilla error console says that `$('rating_div').rating(params ..)` is not a function and the same for my enlarge image one. If I remove the include, all works well again.

If I include the normal jquery.js file AFTER the tools.js one, my normal jquery works but the tools.js one doesn't.

I have seen that other people have had issues like this but I cannot find a resolution. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're including jQuery 1.4.2 *again* with the file you're including (which erases any plugins, since it re-defined the `jquery` object), instead of this:

```
http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/jquery.tools.min.js
```

Use this:

```
http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/all/jquery.tools.min.js
```

[Visit their download page](http://flowplayer.org/tools/download/index.html) (at the bottom) for a full list of CDN files and what they include.

Comment: Awesome, that sorted it. Thanks! p.s Will mark this as the answer when it lets me in 5 mins.